# Retrieve value of NSString via homonymous string name

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I would like to join a series of NSStrings with incremental suffixes via a loop. Once the correct string name is generated inside the loop, how can I  retrieve the corresponding value of the homonymous string defined outside the loop?

```
NSString *Element_1 = @"Andrew";
NSString *Element_2 = @"John";
NSString *Element_3 = @"Jane";
NSString *Element_4 = @"Sarah";

NSString *finalStr;
NSString *elemName;
NSString *elem;
for (int i=1; i<5; i++)
{
    elemName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Element_%i", i];
    elem = //?? value of string with name defined before the loop
    finalStr = [finalStr stringByAppendingString:elem]; 
}
```

Comment: Variables don't work that way. Put your strings in an array, and reference them by index.

Comment: It's also best to avoid declaring variables before they are needed.

Comment: You are correct. The array is the best option. I was just wondering if it was technically possible to do something similar. Thank you.

Comment: It is sometimes technically possible. If `Element_1` and so on are instance variables, you can do it by using key-value coding. Or, if `Element_1` are made into strings up front, you can use them as the keys in a dictionary. But don't.